# Cardinality of solutions for a set of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

How many different sets of solutions satisfy the following formula:
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+\cdots +x_n=A\\
x_1\cdot x_2\cdot x_3\cdot \cdots x_n=B\\
x_1^{-1}+x_2^{-1}+x_3^{-1}+\cdots +x_n^{-1}=C$$

with $n$ unknowns for x_i in a finite field $\mathbb{F}_N^*$?

Is it bounded by $n$?

Comment: The first one is redundant. LHS = RHS for anything. For the last one and $n > 1$ there are continuum many solutions of the form $x_1 = \delta, x_2 = \frac1{\delta}$ and $x_i = 1$ for $i>2$.

Comment: What is the field (or ring?) you are working over? Much will depend on its cardinality. Also, in spite of your title, these equations (except the trivial first one) are not linear.

Comment: Maybe the question was not clear. Given $A,B,C$. How many different sets of x_i satisfy this?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen they lie in a finite field: $x_i \in F_N^*$

Comment: If you want to denote given constants, you should give them _names_ and not call them by formula like $\sum x_i$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen i changed the question since it was wrong.

Comment: Perhaps it's useful to note that the last equation is equivalent to $x_2 \cdots x_n + x_1 x_3 \cdots x_n + \cdots + x_1 \cdots x_{n - 1} = BC$, in which case $A, B, BC$ are all (up to sign) coefficients of the polynomial $(x - x_1) \cdots (x - x_n)$.

Comment: @Travis Yes, actually $B=AC^{-1}$

Comment: For what it's worth, counting points on algebraic varieties (which my previous comment shows this question amounts to) over finite fields leads to some deep questions and powerful results (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_zeta-function for a hint of more).

Comment: In the case that the variety is a curve (I think this is $n = 4$ in our case, but perhaps someone who knows this better can confirm), the number of solutions is $\sim N + 1$, and the error in this estimate is no worse than $2 g \sqrt{N}$, where $g$ is the genus of the curve. (Actually, this counts the number of points on the corresponding projective variety, i.e., includes the so-called "points at infinity".)

Comment: @curious: $BC=A$ is better, because $B=AC^{-1}$ cannot hold for $C=0$.

Comment: @Travis Well i am missing some theory because i cannot interpret why in curves $n=4$ where n is the possible elements of a curve.

Comment: Well from Travis's observation that BC=A it is quite obvious that the bound i am looking for all the different number of solutions is C(n,N) All the possible combinations of n elements out of N. Right? since the equations are linear dependent.As such any possible combinations of $x_i$ work

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, but the variety defined by that equation is not a curve, no?

Comment: @curious Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but I don't follow your argument, as the equations for the $x_i$ are nonlinear.

Comment: @Travis how there are not linear since A=BC?

Answer (score 2):

No, the number of different solutions is not bounded by $n$. Take $n=3$ with
$(A,B,C)=(3,2,2)$. Then, over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_5$ the system
\begin{align*}
x_1+x_2+x_3 & = 3,\\
x_1x_2x_3 & = 2,\\
\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}+\frac{1}{x_3} & = 2
\end{align*}
has $6$ different solutions $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(1,3,4), (1,4,3), (3,1,4),(3,4,1),(4,1,3),(4,3,1)$

Comment: Is there a bounded formula for the number of possible solutions?are there some constants A,B,C that give different number of possible solutions than other?

Comment: I guess the solutions for $x_1$ are all the possible elements in the field. But once $x_1$ is fixed this restricts the values of $x_2$ and $x_3$. Right?

Comment: No, as you see in the example, this is not true. $x_1$ cannot be every element in $\mathbb{F}_5$. It is never zero, too. If we subsitute $x_3$, then we we have two polynomial equations in $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: Yes but $0 \notin \mathbb{F}_q^*$, since it is a field every element has multiplicative inverse so 0 is not part of it

Comment: But you wrote "$x_1$ are all the possible elements in the field". It should be "all the possible elements in the multiplicative group of the field.

Answer (score 0):

A trivial upper bound should be $(N−1)^n$ (just substituting to each variable a non-zero element of the finite field). However, this upper bound holds for any set of equations with $n$ indeterminates on $\mathbb{F}_N$. Hence I believe this can be greatly improved.

Comment: It is not somehow dictated by the set of equations which are 3?

Comment: no, the $(N-1)^n$ bound is the most crude that one can think about as soon we fix the order of the field to be $N$ and the number of variables to be $n$.